# Is it possible to use Index Buffer Objects (IBO) with the function 'glMultiDrawElements'?

Tags: opengl, glsl

I develop a small 3D engine using OpenGL and GLSL.

I have incorporated a vertex data batching system which the goal is to gather all the geometry (all the objects) sharing the same shader program and same transformations in a unique Vertex Buffer Object (VBO) thereby minimizing the state changes (binding) and draw calls too.

I currently use the function 'glMultiDrawElements' to render a specific batch of data (so a single draw call). So, for instance, if I have in my batch 3 meshes, I have 3 arrays of indices too (one for each mesh) organized in a 'GLvoid **' array (a double array). So to render my 3 meshes I have a unique call of glMultiDrawElements but I have to pass directly to the function the double array of elements in parameter.

But I wonder (for a question of performance) if it's possible to store all the elements (the double array of elements) in a Index Buffer Object (IBO)(like it's possible to do with glDrawElements -> here a simple array of elements) and bind it before the glMultiDrawElements call... I don't think so because it's a double array and not a simple array but maybe (and I hope so) I'm wrong.

Here's an example using glDrawElements (pseudo code):

```
[...]

//Setup data

[...]

#define OFFSET_BUFFER(offset) ((char*)NULL + offset)

foreach (pMeshGeometry from meshes) //iterates for each mesh of the scene
{
    pMeshGeometry->GetIndexBuffer().Lock(); //Bind IBO
    {
         glDrawElements(pMeshGeometry->GetPrimitiveType(),       
             pMeshGeometry->GetIndexBufferSize(), pMeshGeometry->GetIndexBuffer().GetType(), OFFSET_BUFFER(0)); //Render a specific mesh eccording to indices
    }
}
```

For the moment I use glMultiDrawElement this way:

```
glMultiDrawElements(GL_TRIANGLES, &this->m_CountElementArray[0], GL_UNSIGNED_INT,
                    (const GLvoid **)&this->m_IndexAttribArray[0], this->m_CountElementArray.size()); //I enter the array of pointer directly in parameter
```

So, maybe to following example should be possible:

```
#define OFFSET_BUFFER(offset) ((char**)NULL + offset) //Something like this

glMultiDrawElements(GL_TRIANGLES, &this->m_CountElementArray[0], GL_UNSIGNED_INT,
                    OFFSET_BUFFER(0), this->m_CountElementArray.size()); //Something like this
```

So if it's not possible to do this, I've thought to the function 'glDrawRangeElements'. For my example of 3 meshes into a unique VBO, I'll just have to bind an IBO before each glDrawRangeElements call (here, 3 draw calls for each mesh -> so a loop of glDrawRangeElements). So here it's clearly possible to use IBO.

This method will work for sure but I don't think it's the best one! I think it's possible to do this using glMultiDrawElements with an IBO but I don't know how to do this.

Or maybe it's really impossible. Maybe the fact to enter directy in parameter an array of indices is faster than the method using glDrawRangeElements and its IBO and so the usage of IBO in this case is maybe deprecated and so not adapted.

What do you think of that ?

Comment: _Please_ use some line breaks. This giant paragraph is near impossible to read.

Comment: What exactly are you asking here? Even with line breaks I'm not sure.

Comment: Sorry I thought it was clear. To sum up I wonder if it's possible to use IBO with glMultiDrawElements rather than using directly the double array of indices in parameter.

Comment: @user1364743: There is no "double array". There is an array of pointers/offsets. There is [ARB_multi_draw_indirect](https://www.opengl.org/registry/specs/ARB/multi_draw_indirect.txt).  But I'm not sure if that is what you are asking for.

Comment: Sorry I wanted to say array of pointers and not double array. I've updated my question adding a source code (pseudo code) example with the method 'glDrawElements'. As you can see before the main loop I setup all the vertex data into a VBO and all the indices data into a IBO. After that, in the main loop I use the macro OFFSET_BUFFER. This works. Is it possible to use a such macro for the function 'glMultiDrawElements' (and so using IBO rather than using directly an array of pointers) ?

Comment: Or is it possible to store an array of pointer into an Index Buffer Object ? If it's possible so it will be possible to use IBO with glMultiDrawElements. Thanks again.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You certainly can use index buffers with `glMultiDrawElements()`. Client side index arrays are deprecated in the OpenGL Core Profile. So if `glMultiDrawElements()` could not operate with index buffers, there would be no way to use it anymore.

To see how it works, we need to look at what the arguments of `glMultiDrawElements()` mean. The call is basically just a shortcut for multiple `glDrawElements()` calls. The signature is:

```
void glMultiDrawElements(GLenum mode, const GLsizei* count, GLenum type,  
                         const GLvoid** indices, GLsizei primcount);
```

Aside from some error checking details, this call is equivalent to:

```
for (int i = 0; i < primcount; ++i) {
    glDrawElements(mode, count[i], type, indices[i]);
}
```

Now remember that if an index buffer is bound, the last argument to `glDrawElements()` is a relative offset into the buffer. So the corresponding 4th element of `glMultiDrawElements()` is an **array of offsets** into the buffer. The 2nd argument is a matching array of counts.

People often use a macro to hide the cumbersome type conversion of the last argument of `glDrawElements()`. Using this:

```
#define BUFFER_OFFSET(offset) (static_cast<char*>(0) + (offset))
```

As an example, let's say we have an index buffer bound, and we want to draw 3 sub-ranges of the index array with a single call:

- 20 indices starting at index 10 in the buffer.
- 30 indices starting at index 40 in the buffer.
- 10 indices starting at index 90 in the buffer.

I'll use unsigned shorts (GLushort) for the index type. So the index buffer would have been populated with data from a `GLushort indexA[100]` at some point in the past. The setup and draw call then looks like this:

```
GLsizei count[3] = {20, 30, 10};
GLvoid* indices[3] = {
    BUFFER_OFFSET(10 * sizeof(GLushort)),
    BUFFER_OFFSET(40 * sizeof(GLushort)),
    BUFFER_OFFSET(90 * sizeof(GLushort)),
};
glMultiDrawElements(GL_TRIANGLE_STRIP, count, GL_UNSIGNED_SHORT, indices, 3);
```

Comment: Thank you very much for this complete answer. I'm sure your solution is the best one and it is very logical. I'm going to integrate it into my program. Have a good day. Bye!